# On the same postgres server, is it possible to have one database with md5 authentication and another one with scram-sha-256?

Tags: postgresql, md5

On the same postgres server, is it possible to have one database with md5 authentication and another one with scram-sha-256? I will use separate database user for connecting the two databases but from the same set of clients.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible in PostgreSQL 12 and it depends on password encryption which is not a database property but a instance parameter that can be changed at session level:

> The availability of the different password-based authentication
>   methods depends on how a user's password on the server is encrypted
>   (or hashed, more accurately). This is controlled by the configuration
>   parameter **password_encryption** at the time the password is set.

See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/auth-password.html

Note also that:

> To ease transition from the md5 method to the newer SCRAM method, if
>   md5 is specified as a method in pg_hba.conf but the user's password on
>   the server is encrypted for SCRAM (see below), then SCRAM-based
>   authentication will automatically be chosen instead.

Comment: You should mention that the meaning of `md5` in `pg_hba.conf` varies according to the way the password is hashed, otherwise your answer makes no sense (the questoin is about authentication methods, not about the way passwords are hashed).